# How to Get DWR Token in Java

Tags: java, spring, token, csrf, dwr

I want to get generated DWR token. I can see it in cookies, but how can I get it in java?

I have `dwr3.jar` and called `import org.directwebremoting.json.parse.javacc.Token;` in controller.

But there is no any `getToken()` or something similar to getting token number when I create `Token` object `Token token = new Token();`.

Is there any way to get DWR CSRF token?